different results in post 3.3 vs 2.2
I was getting different results when I upgraded to postGIS 3.3. Ultimately to narrow down the problem, I ran a simple transformation from SRID 900913 to 4316 and to my surprise, I got different results.
See below
postgis 3.3.3 on postgres 15
gis=# select ST_AsText(ST_Transform('010100002031BF0D00CDCCCC1CD50E5F41EC51B81E6583F2C0'::geometry(Geometry,900913),4326));
                  st_astext                  
---------------------------------------------
 POINT(73.13770833824148 -0.685769673774372)

postgis 2.2.1 on postgres 9.5
gis=# select ST_AsText(ST_Transform('010100002031BF0D00CDCCCC1CD50E5F41EC51B81E6583F2C0'::geometry(Geometry,900913),4326));
                 st_astext                  
--------------------------------------------
 POINT(73.1377083382415 -0.681179307212437)

I have narrowed down the issue to a simple query which is giving different results on  versions.
Any ideas?

PostGIS relies on the Proj library for spatial transformations. Over time, Proj has undergone significant updates that improve accuracy and handling of coordinate systems. These updates can lead to different transformation results due to:
Changes in Transformation Algorithms: Newer versions of Proj may use more accurate transformation algorithms.
Updates to EPSG Definitions: The EPSG database, which defines coordinate systems, is updated periodically. These updates can change the parameters used in transformations.
Bug Fixes and Improvements: Each version of Proj fixes bugs and improves performance, which can alter transformation results.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
